# Custom table view SwiftUI iOS

Tags: swiftui

I need to create a table so that the text in the cell expands to the desired size.
I create Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [String] = [
        "1 One Line",
        "1 One Line",
        "1 One Line"
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.hash) { (item) in
                    HStack(spacing: 1) {
                        Text(item)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        Text("One Line")
                            .frame(width: 70)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        Text("One Line")
                            .frame(width: 70)
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
                }
                // MARK: Total
                HStack(spacing: 1) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.white)
                    Text("One Line")
                        .frame(width: 141)
                        .background(Color.white)
                }
            }
            .padding(1)
            .background(Color.orange)
        }
        .padding(15)
    }
}
```

and it works well:
[image]
But if the text becomes multi-line, then the table breaks:

```
let items: [String] = [
    "1 One Line",
    "2 Two Line\nTwo Line",
    "3 Three lines\nThree lines\nThree lines"
]
```

borders are getting wider:
[image]

if you make maxHeight = infinity then this solves the problem with borders, but the lines become equal to the maximum height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible solution is to use `maxHeight: .infinity` with `.fixedSize`

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.hash) { (item) in
                    HStack(spacing: 1) {
                        Text(item)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        Text("One Line")
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        Text("One Line")
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            
                    }
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) //<---Here
                }
                // MARK: Total
                HStack(spacing: 1) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.white)
                    Text("One Line")
                        .frame(width: 137)
                        .background(Color.white)
                }
            }
            .padding(1)
            .background(Color.orange)
        }
        .padding(15)
    }
```

[image]